# Java Calendar not support 29th February

Tags: java, validation, calendar, leap-year

In this method when passing 2020-03-01 as a date object the output is obtained as 2019-02-28. But I need it as 2020-02-29. The problem occurs only inputting date after 29th February in leap years.

```
  public DateTime add(DateTime p_dateTime, int p_field, int p_amount) {   //p_field = 1, p_amount = 1;
    Calendar calendar = this.getCalendar(p_dateTime);
    calendar.add(p_field, p_amount);
    DateTime dateTime = this.getDateTime(calendar);
    return dateTime;
  }
```

Can I know what the problem is. Any advice?

The Calendar calendar object results shows like below.

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time = 1582910939192, areFieldsSet = true, areAllFieldsSet = true, lenient = true, zone = sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id = "Asia/Colombo", offset = 19800000, dstSavings = 0, useDaylight = false, transitions = 9, lastRule = null], firstDayOfWeek = 2, minimalDaysInFirstWeek = 4, ERA = 1, YEAR = 2020, MONTH = 1, WEEK_OF_YEAR = 9, WEEK_OF_MONTH = 4, DAY_OF_MONTH = 28, DAY_OF_YEAR = 59, DAY_OF_WEEK = 6, DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH = 4, AM_PM = 1, HOUR = 10, HOUR_OF_DAY = 22, MINUTE = 58, SECOND = 59, MILLISECOND = 192, ZONE_OFFSET = 19800000, DST_OFFSET = 0]
```

Comment: Please consider switching to the Java 8 date API, which probably does not have this issue.

Comment: Does this mean that the problem is with the Calendar API and not with the method implementation?

Comment: Not 100% certain, but `Calendar` is deprecated, and has been for sometime.  Ditch it, and use Java 8 date instead.

Comment: Use java.util.Date class or java8 api to do operations. Calendar is not something, you should be using for these operations.

Comment: What is `getCalendar`? What is `DateTime`? What is `The timestamp `1582910939192` represents `2020-02-28T17:28:59.192Z`.  Also, `p_field` would be representing `Calendar.YEAR`. You're adding a year? Why? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `java.util.Calendar` certainly handles 29th of February in a correct way. It is a very old class in stable production for many years and you can be sure that such bugs if it has ever been there is fixed. I rather suspect that something with your `DateTime`-conversion to or from `Calendar` is wrong. Please show that code.

Comment: @PrateekJain Agree not to use `Calendar`, but `java.util.Date` is worse for this job, I don’t think you’ll get through. Do use java.time.

Comment: I’m afraid we cannot answer this question without [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). PS Is that the `DateTime` class from Joda-Time?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you do either of 2.:

1. If the `DateTime` class that you are using is the one from Joda-Time, go all-in on Joda-Time.
2. Migrate the whole thing to java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

In any case do not use the `Calendar` class. That class is poorly deigned and long outdated. And mixing different date-time libraries will just over-complicate things for you, so avoid doing that. To be honest I find that a method that takes a Joda-Time `DateTime` and a field number from `Calendar` as arguments is a bad design.

### Joda-Time

A design of your method for Joda-Time may look like this:

```
public static DateTime add(DateTime pDateTime, DurationFieldType pField, int pAmount) {
    return pDateTime.withFieldAdded(pField, pAmount);
}
```

Please enjoy how much simpler it is compared to the method in the question. We may use the method for example in this way:

```
    DateTime now = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Colombo"));
    DateTime oneYearLater = add(now, DurationFieldType.years(), 1);
    System.out.println("Now = " + now + ". Next year = " + oneYearLater + ' ');
```

Output when I ran the code just now was:

> Now = 2020-05-25T09:14:19.880+05:30. Next year = 2021-05-25T09:14:19.880+05:30

### java.time

The java.time code is similar, though maybe a bit more easy to read:

```
public static ZonedDateTime add(ZonedDateTime pDateTime, TemporalUnit pField, int pAmount) {
    return pDateTime.plus(pAmount, pField);
}
```

Use like this:

```
    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Colombo"));
    ZonedDateTime oneYearLater = add(now, ChronoUnit.YEARS, 1);
    System.out.println("Now = " + now + ". Next year = " + oneYearLater + ' ');
```

> Now = 2020-05-25T09:14:39.732386+05:30[Asia/Colombo]. Next year = 2021-05-25T09:14:39.732386+05:30[Asia/Colombo]

### Links

- [Documentation of Joda-Time `DateTime.withFieldsAdded()`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withFieldAdded-org.joda.time.DurationFieldType-int-)
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.